# How does ContentDocument/ContenVersion relates to EmailMessage?

Tags: emailmessage

I need to get attachments when trigger on EmailMessage executes.

How do I find them?

**Edit**: The EmailMessage is created via Lightning for Outlook plugin.

Comment: emailmessage related to what? Cases? your question is not very clear, additionally what have you tried and/or researched? please update your post accordingly, thanks

Comment: @glls EmailMessage is created via Lightning for Outlook. A task is usually created, tho I do not find it super relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. It's ContentDocumentLink.ContentDocumentId.

e.g.

> SELECT Id, LinkedEntityId, ContentDocumentId, IsDeleted, SystemModstamp, ShareType, Visibility FROM ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId = '02s550000012345678'

02s550000012345678 is EmailMessage id.